# AS3, scroller #1137 error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

This is an AS3 scroller I've been trying to convert from AS2.

I appreciate the help, but I'm still getting '#error 1137 incorrect
number of arguments'. How do I get this scroller to work?
Thanks,

```
//SCROLLING GALLERY
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, masterLoop);
function masterLoop(e:Event){
    var mouseMin:int = 0;
    var mouseMax:int = 0;

    var BUTTON:Array = new Array();
    BUTTON[0] = z1;
    BUTTON[1] = z2;
    BUTTON[2] = z3;
    BUTTON[3] = z4;
    BUTTON[4] = z5;

    for(var i:int=0; i<5; i++){
        var mouseX:int = 0;
        if (mouseX > -360 && mouseX < 360)
        {
            mouseX = Math.ceil(mouseX);
        }else{
            mouseX = 20;
        }

        if (i<12){
            var menuX:int = 0;
            var menuX2:int = 0;
            menuX = Math.ceil(BUTTON[i], x);
            //menuX2 = Math.ceil(BUTTON[i+1], x);
        }else{
            //menuX2 = Math.ceil(BUTTON[0], x);
        }
        if (i < 12 && menuX2 > menuX){
            BUTTON[i+1], x, menuX + 130;
        }   
        if (mouseX < mouseMin && menuX < 1060) {
            diff = (mouseMin-mouseX)/20;
            BUTTON[i], x, (menuX+diff);
        }else if (mouseX <= mouseMin && menuX >= 1060) { 
            diff = Math.ceil((mouseMin-mouseX)/15);
            diff = diff + (menuX - 1060);
            BUTTON[i], x, (-500 + diff);
        } 
        if (mouseX > mouseMax && menuX > -500) {
            diff = (mouseX-mouseMax)/20;
            BUTTON[i], x, menuX-diff; 
        } else if (mouseX >= mouseMax && menuX <= -500) {
            var diff:int = 0;
            diff = Math.ceil((mouseMin-mouseX)/15);
            diff = diff + (menuX + 500);
            BUTTON[i], x, (1060 + diff);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the answer to your previous question, setting the property `x` of `BUTTON[i]` is done like this:

```
BUTTON[i].x = -500 + diff
```

NOT like this:

```
BUTTON[i], x, (-500 + diff);
```

**EDIT**
Also note, your lines checking for i < 12 will always evaluate to true since i is a counter from 0 to 5.

**EDIT 2**
Also note, your code initializing your array should be outside of the EnterFrame event handler as you are needlessly reinitializing the array on each frame.

Answer (score 1):

Math.ceil only takes one argument. You are passing two into it @:

```
menuX = Math.ceil(BUTTON[i], x);
```

Comment: point for diagnosis. The gallery doesn't move. But there's no error:)